# Как создать бота в телеграм, который при добавлении в чат пишет в личные сообщения приветствие

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Я веду сообщество и хотел бы создать чат бота random coffee, который будет напоминать о себе сразу при вступлении человека в чат. То есть человек добавился и бот пишет в личные сообщения ему автоматом приветствие, онбординг и ненавязчиво приглашает поучаствовать в рандом кофе. Я знаю, что можно сделать так с каналом, но про чаты я не нашел информации. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли способы это реализовать

Answer (score 0):

Нужно слушать событие на нового пользователя в чате и отправлять ему в лс сообщение
Пример:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
def welcome_new_member(message):
    user_id = message.json['new_chat_participant']['id']
    bot.send_message(user_id, 'Поиграем?')
```